# Getting <unk> as result of voice recognition in sphinx4, java

Tags: java, speech-recognition, speech, cmusphinx, sphinx4

I am trying to control my Arduino with voice using Java. I am using Sphinx4 for that... I have made own .gram file

```
grammar servo;

public <servo> = <command> <endPolite>;

<command> = <action> <object> <where>;
<action> = (turn | start | exit);
<object> = [the | a] (motor | program);
<where> = [left | right];

<endPolite> = [ please | thanks | thank you ];
```

Here it is!
And my problem is what I am always getting this -->

```
<unk>
```

as result of recognition. It's Sting. And I get it using this -->

```
String utterance = recognizer.getResult().getHypothesis();
```

I can give my Java class if it's needed

Comment: Try with prerecorded audio first

Comment: Your grammar file looks okay to me. Can we please see an excerpt of your code? Please give us a minimal working example that produces your output.